# What would be the best way to wrap an enum

Tags: c#, enums, word-wrap

I have my enum, which I don't want to share between layers.

So I was thinking wrapping it up would be neat.

But how ? There are many items, manualy writing down all items isn't a solution. 
Also the enum is getting generated.

I'd like to keep the intelisense.

Comment: First obvious question: why don't you want to share it between layers?

Comment: Because the enum is in the DataAccess assembly which I don't want to share. And I cannot move the enum to other assembly because the assembly is getting generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can cast to/from `int` (or the defined underlying type, which defaults to `int`), but this is brittle; it doesn't protect you when somebody removes an entry causing them to be re-numbered, or changes the meaning of `7` from `Blah.TrivialDetail` to `Blah.CriticalFail`.

If you want intellisense, all parties are going to need to know *something* about the numbers, so IMO you might just as well share the enum via some common assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way (not so elegant) is to create another enum in the assembly that can be shared. You need to create some build action to clone the generated enum from data assembly to new sharable enum. If generated enum is in a separate file then simple file copy (with change in namespace) as post-build event to DAL project or Pre-Build event in shared assembly project would do the trick. If the generated file contains some other stuff then you need to do some text processing in your favorite language (powershell, c#) to extract enumeration definition.